# Enabling PHP 7.4 on scotch box

Tags: php, apache

I am running scotch box vagrant box (pro version). currently if I ssh and type php -v it comes up as php 7.4.1.

When I run an php file via the website, it comes up as running php 7.0.

How do I change scotch box to be using the 7.4 module for apache instead of 7.0?